# What editors have vi emulation AND delphi hightlighting support?

Tags: delphi, vim, editor

Hello I've recently been tasked with working on a Delphi project. Before I was using Visual Studio with ViEmu and now I can't live without some form of vi emulation. Are there any editors with Delphi syntax highlighting and a vi mode?

Note: I won't be using this editor for compiling Delphi projects. I just want to use it to edit individual `.pas` files

Comment: What additional requirements are there which excludes gVim or other actual vi variants from consideration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about just using Vim/gVim?  If it doesn't have a Delphi syntax file by default, there are some you can find online.

http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=3078

Comment: Now it seems obvious especially with the "graphical" version of vim